# How to get item name instead of item id in django restframework (foreignkey case)

Tags: django-rest-framework

***I am trying to get itemwise inventory desired result is like this***

[
{
'item' : shoes,
'total_unit' : 134
},
{
'item': sneaker,
'unit': 100
}
]

***but I am getting result like***

[
{
"item": 5,
"unit": 134
},
{
"item": 4,
"unit": 100
}
]

***I want to get item name instead of id***

***Models.py***

```
class Item(models.Model):
item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
srn_code = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name='categories',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.item_name


class Transaction(models.Model):
category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
item = models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
size = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=20)
unit = models.IntegerField()
unit_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)
supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
tran_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False,auto_created=False,blank=False)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.item.item_name} {self.unit}"
```

***serializer.py***

```
class InventorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
item = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
total_unit = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

class Meta():
    model = Transaction
    fields = ['item','total_unit']
```

***views.py***

```
class InventoryModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
queryset = Transaction.objects.all()
serializer_class = InventorySerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    return Transaction.objects.values('item').annotate(
        total_unit = Sum('unit')
    ).order_by('item')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting my question, I have sorted out my question, my solution is below, if anybody needs or gets query like this, then its might be helpful.

I have declared a method in serializers class for get item_name from another table

```
class InventorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
item = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
total_unit = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
item_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta():
    model = Transaction
    fields = ['item','item_name','total_unit']

def get_item_name(self, obj):
    item_obj = Item.objects.filter(id=obj['item']).first()
    item_name = model_to_dict(item_obj)
    return item_name['item_name']
```

`